# Formulario de celular, telefone auto complete

Tags: javascript, html

Estou iniciando meus estudos, queria saber como fazer para quando eu digitar no formulario o numero de telefone EX: 00000000000 , o formulario ir completando os campos ex: (00) 0 00000000 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sugiro que veja os videos do rodrigo branas no youtube. Assista primeiro ["desvendando a linguagem javascript"](https://youtu.be/OqR0hE-DQn4) depois quando assistir sobre angularjs vai ter uma video aula sobre mascaras acho que é exatamente o que tu quer fazer

Comment: Obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu uso um plugin do jQuery chamado [jQuery Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/). No link você vai encontrar um exemplo chamado "São Paulo Celphones" que provavelmente é o que você busca.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, era isso mesmo o que eu estava procurando.